# $L\otimes_K L$ reduced and $\text{ker}(L\otimes_K L\to L)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Taking $L/K$ field $I\subset L\otimes_K L$ the kernel of the multiplication $L\otimes_K L\to L$. I want to prove (if it's true?) that $L\otimes_K L$ is reduced iff $I/I^2=0$ (in the context of Kahler differential, but I'd like to prove it directly).

I can't get it: taking for example $x\otimes y\in I$ ie $xy=0$ how can I get $x\otimes y\in I^2$? $(x\otimes1)(1\otimes y)$ doesn't match because $x\otimes 1\notin I$.

Any idea?

I want to prove that because I want to prove $\Omega_{L/K}=0$ iff $L$ separable over $K$ and I know that $L$ separable over $K$ iff $L\otimes_K L$ reduced and that $\Omega_{L/K}=I/I^2$. I know there is other proof with the usual definition of Kähler differential but I'd like to use the definition $I/I^2$.

Comment: What hypotheses do you assume on the extension $L/K$? (Finite? Algebraic?) Second, you should know that no single pure tensor will be in the kernel without already being zero: $x\otimes y$ being in the kernel means that $xy=0$ which, as $L$ is a domain, means $x=0$ or $y=0$, so $x\otimes y=0$. A better way to think about the kernel is as the span of elements of the form $a\otimes b - c\otimes d$ where $ab=cd$ but the tensors aren't equal.

Comment: @KReiser I guess that $L/K$ is finite because I want to apply this when $L/K$ separable finite.

Comment: Ok hence I take $a\otimes b-c\otimes d$ with $ab-cd=0$ ie $ab=cd$: why such a tensor should be in $I^2$... I guess some abstract nonsense trick here

Comment: It is enough to assume $L/K$ is algebraic. I do not know which proof you do want, it will be very hard only using $I/I^2$. This follows immediately from the "cotangent" exact sequence for Kähler differentials. You may chek this in Section 6.1 of Qing Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry.